# Error when trying to connect to gRPC endpoint from a UI tool or proxy tool

Tags: .net-core, grpc

I'm testing gRPC with .NetCore and looked up for a GUI tool or something that can help me to test my endpoint like testing REST API.
I found a proxy tool:  [grpc-json-proxy](https://github.com/jnewmano/grpc-json-proxy) that can be used with Postman tool (also found another GUI tool: [grpcox](https://github.com/gusaul/grpcox)).
Using any tool gives an error like the following when trying to connect to the endpoint:

> unable to do request err=[Post
> http://localhost:5001/greet.Greeter/SayHello: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001:
> connect: connection refused]

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Another GUI tool to test gRPC services is [Kreya](https://kreya.app). It supports server reflection, proto imports, environments and authentication schemes. 

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Kreya.*

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, are you confident the gRPC server is listening on `localhost:50051`? You may confirm this (on Linux) using:

```sh
GRPC="50051"
ss --tcp --listening --processes "sport = :${GRPC}"
```

> **NOTE** you may need to `sudo ss ...` to get the process

Or more simply:

```sh
telnet localhost 50051
```

If you get `Connected to...` that's a good sign

Then, if you're using either of these tools through docker, you'll need to ensure the container can access the host's `50051` port. To do this, run the container use `--net=host`. This will make the host's port available to the container.

I use [`grpCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl)

Comment: The server is surly running and responding because I wrote a client in .Net Core and it worked.

Comment: Does the .NET client use TLS? If it does, you'll need to ensure you're tool points to `https://`. Alternatively, give grpCurl a whirl, I know that works.

Comment: Depending on the documentation of this tool https://github.com/jnewmano/grpc-json-proxy I should always use the HTTP and the proxy will establish the https connection for me.